# figuring out objects created 30 min ago in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a DateTimeField called created in my model and I would like to get all the objects where created date is 30 min or more. How would query this using MyModel.objects(....) in django?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
import datetime
created_time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)
old_objects = MyModel.objects.filter(created__lte=created_time)
```

See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/ for more information on creating queries, filtering, etc.

Comment: This should be the opposite filter if the OP wants all items in the last 30 min. It should be `gte` as you have a "30 minutes ago" timestamp and you are looking for anything greater than that

Answer (score 1):

Use this function:

```
.filter(created__lte=datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=60 * 30))
```